# Compare dates in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers

I have two tables, round and event.  One round has many events.

```
create table round (
    round_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    round_start_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    round_end_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT round_pk PRIMARY KEY (round_id)
);

create table event (
    event_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    round_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    event_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT event_pk PRIMARY KEY (event_id),
    CONSTRAINT round_fk FOREIGN KEY (round_id) REFERENCES round (round_id),
);
```

When a row is inserted into the event table, I want to use a trigger to compare the event_date field of the newly inserted row to the round_start_date and round_end_date fields in its corresponding entry in the round table.  If event_date is earlier than round_start_date, round_start_date should be updated with the new event_date.  If event_date is after round_end_date, round_end_date should be updated with the new event_date.

This is my trigger.  It does not work, and I do not understand why.  I cannot find anywhere on the web where anyone else has tried to use a datetime type in a trigger, so I have no frame of reference for where I am going wrong.

```
create trigger update_round_date
after insert on event for each row
begin
    declare curSdate datetime;
    declare curEdate datetime;
    set curSdate = (select round_start_date from round where round_id = NEW.round_id);
    set curEdate = (select round_end_date from round where round_id = NEW.round_id);
    if (NEW.event_date < curSdate) then
        update round set round_start_date = NEW.event_date where round_id = NEW.round_id;
    else if (NEW.event_date > curEdate) then
        update round set round_end_date = NEW.event_date where round_id = NEW.round_id;
    end if;
end;
```

EDIT: I simply can't create the trigger. phpMyAdmin gives me this error:
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4"

EDIT 2: Updated with a delimiter set

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger update_round_date
after insert on event for each row
begin
    declare curSdate datetime;
    declare curEdate datetime;
    set curSdate = (select round_start_date from round where round_id = NEW.round_id);
    set curEdate = (select round_end_date from round where round_id = NEW.round_id);
    if (NEW.event_date < curSdate) then
        update round set round_start_date = NEW.event_date where round_id = NEW.round_id;
    else if (NEW.event_date > curEdate) then
        update round set round_end_date = NEW.event_date where round_id = NEW.round_id;
    end if;
end$$
```

This returns the error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13"

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or is it updating the row with something strange?

Comment: This is the error phpMyAdmin gives me when I try and create the trigger: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4.

Comment: Possibly forget to set your delimiter to something other than ";" first?

Comment: Ok, got up to line 13 now. Try a semicolon after the last end?

Comment: I tried "end$$;" and "end;$$", neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is probably stopping at the first ';', interpreting your command as:

```
create trigger update_round_date 
after insert on event for each row
begin
    declare curSdate datetime;
```

You have to set your delimiter to something else first, then terminate the create trigger command with that delimiter instead (and put the delimiter back at the end):

```
delimiter ^

create trigger update_round_date 
after insert on event for each row
begin
    ...
end;

^

delimiter ;
```

I believe the last semicolon after `end` may be necessary.

Comment: It's still giving me the same error message regardless of how I write it.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that in phpMyAdmin, the "end" on lines 13 and 14 aren't being highlighted like the other keywords.

Comment: I'm marking this one as the answer even though Devart's answer came first because this one helped me fix my trigger so I understood what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with delimiters in phpmyadmin, try to use this trigger -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER INSERT
ON event
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE
    round
  SET
    round_start_date =
      IF(NEW.event_date < round_start_date, NEW.event_date, round_start_date),
    round_end_date =
      IF(NEW.event_date > round_end_date, NEW.event_date, round_end_date)
  WHERE
    round_id = NEW.round_id;
```

Comment: This worked, but I would still like to know why my original attempt (and with the delimiter set) did not work.

Comment: As far as I know old phpmyadmin versions don't support scripts with source objects - procedures, triggers..., where BEGIN...END clause is met. Your trigger should work too, if you will run it in another MySQL client.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin v3.5.2.2, which I believe is the latest available version.

Comment: Change `else if` to `elseif`.