# Trigger compare two datetime mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want a trigger which compare two datetime.

Here my trigger:

[image]

EDIT :

```
create trigger updateRealisee after update on ladi.DSMSreservation for each row 
begin
declare mnt datetime;
mnt=(select NOW()); 
if :new.date < mnt  then
     :new.realisee = 1;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: what is the issue you have now? also please post your code instead of the image

Comment: Have you set a delimiter first?  Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595319/compare-dates-in-mysql-trigger

Comment: @dsharew now I have : "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 "

Comment: @daticon when I put delimiter I have an other problem "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=(select NOW()); 
if :new.date < mnt  then
     :new.realisee = 1;
end if;
e' at line 4 "

Comment: @daticon Yes, I tried to remove ":" but it's still not working. Concerning date is an "datetime" and "realisee" is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that there are several restrictions on an **after udpate** trigger:

- You can not create an AFTER trigger on a view.

  You can not update the NEW values.

  You can not update the OLD values.

However, you can change it to a before insert trigger.

I have tested the code below and it works.  Of course, it only works on those you are newly inserting, not ones that already exist.  For the ones that already exit.... simply run:

```
update TEST.DSMSreservation set realisee = 1 where date < NOW();
```

Then... the following complete code to create a table, trigger, and add rows provides an example how it works on newly added rows:

```
create database TEST;
USE TEST;
CREATE TABLE TEST.DSMSreservation
(
   date DATETIME  NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   realisee INT  NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

delimiter $$
create trigger updateRealisee before insert on TEST.DSMSreservation 
for each row
   begin
      IF (new.date < NOW())  THEN
      SET new.realisee = 1;
   end if;
   end;
$$
delimiter ;  

INSERT INTO DSMSreservation VALUES ('2012-06-08 12:13:14',0);
INSERT INTO DSMSreservation VALUES ('2017-06-08 12:13:14',0);
INSERT INTO DSMSreservation VALUES ('2016-06-08 10:13:14',0);
INSERT INTO DSMSreservation (date) VALUES ('2016-06-08 16:13:14');
```

Running these two mysql statements will resolve what you were trying to accomplish with your original trigger.

Please mark as answer if this has answered your question.

Comment: When I try your solution it's doesn't works : "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=(select NOW());
IF (new.yourdatetimefieldname < mnt)  THEN
   SET new.realise' at line 4 "

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer above.  The main issue is the after update triggger cannot do what you wanted to as it violates restrictions.  I've also removed the unnecessary declare statement.